# How to hide Shell Tabbed from another Page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Shell Tabbed Page, and it's working fine. But when I navigate to a new Page using

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```

Then inside the Second Page Shell Tabbed also showing, so I need to hide this shell from this page.

How to do this?

From Sheel backend cs page I can hide this,I also try with Messaging Center to hide this but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page just add:

```
 Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
```

Here is a sample:

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
             x:Class="Sample.MySamplePage"
             Title="TitleTest">

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Hello Xamarin"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```